# Is there something that looks like white space but it is not and how to remove it?

Tags: python, string, replace, special-characters

I have a string that seems to have a lot of white spaces (actually between each symbols I see a white space). To make it clear this is the string:

```
{ " d a t a " : { " i d " : " 1 0 b a 8 7 3 8 - b 0 0 9 - 4 1 2 0 - 9 e c 1 - 4 1 7 a 6 e a 1 a 6 1 f " , " t i m e " : 1 4 4 5 2 6 0 9 8 6 7 5 2 } , " e x p i r e s " : 1 4 5 3 0 9 6 7 8 6 7 5 2 }
```

I try to remove the white spaces in the way I always did:

```
z = z.replace(" ","")
```

But it does not work. For example this code:

```
print type(z), len(z)
z = z.replace(" ","")
print type(z), len(z)
```

prints the following:

```
<type 'str'> 198
<type 'str'> 198
```

So, after the removal of white spaces the string has the same length as before. In addition to that I save the new strings (where the white spaces are supposed to be removed) into a text file. When I open this file with a text editor I do see the white spaces! If I try to remove them withing the text editor (with search and replace) they are removed.

So, my question is why Python cannot remove these "special" white spaces and how to remove them?

Comment: Have you tried checking e.g. `z[0] == ' '` (compare to an *actual* space), or `ord(z[0])`, or looking at `repr(z)`, or... Where did this data come from?

Comment: What is the source? Is it utf-16 encoded text (perhaps you see zero bytes as whitespace)? Have you tried `print z.decode('utf-16le')`?

Comment: Is it unicode perhaps?

Comment: You can iterate over the string and see what each character is: `for c in my_str: print ord(c)`. A space would produce `32`; other values will indicate what your unknown characters are.

Comment: If it is any kind of actual whitespace, you could use regex: `import re; re.sub(r'\s','',z)`

Comment: I have just tired to use `ord(c)` and I get `0` for the characters that I have interpreted as white spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have just tired to use ord(c) and I get 0 for the characters that I have interpreted as white spaces.

It indicates that the input data is utf-16 text. If zero bytes follow what appears to be ascii characters e.g., `b'a\0'` then it is `'utf-16le'` (little-endian):

```
>>> b'd\0a\0t\0a\0'.decode('utf-16le')
u'data'
```

Don't use `.replace(b'\0', b'')`; it will break on the first non-ascii character e.g., `b'\xac '` (euro sign encoded using utf-16le character encoding).

Answer (score 2):

Since you said in your last comment that `ord(c)` returns 0 for this character, you could slightly change your code and remove this particular null character:

```
z = z.replace(chr(0), "")
```

Now it shouldn't contain any "white space":

```
print z
>> {"data":{"id":"10ba8738-b009-4120-9ec1-417a6ea1a61f","time":1445260986752},"expires":1453096786752}
```

EDIT:

Here is also a link to the ASCII table, where you can see that it is the null char:

http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Thank you. By the way, the following solution (proposed in the comments)  also works: `z = z.decode('utf-16le')`.

Comment: @Roman Yes, that should be even better if you have to perform other operations on the string. It was just hard from here to guess the encoding of your file, so I proposed this somewhat naive, but effective approach.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `string_01` with the same string as the one shared by OP

```
string_01 = '{ " d a t a " : { " i d " : " 1 0 b a 8 7 3 8 - b 0 0 9 - 4 1 2 0 - 9 e c 1 - 4 1 7 a 6 e a 1 a 6 1 f " , " t i m e " : 1 4 4 5 2 6 0 9 8 6 7 5 2 } , " e x p i r e s " : 1 4 5 3 0 9 6 7 8 6 7 5 2 } '
```

With `len(string_01)) = 198`

There are various ways to remove the spacing.

---

**Option 1**

Using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), more specifically [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) as follows

```
import re

string_02 = re.sub(r'\s+', '', string_01)

[Out]: {"data":{"id":"10ba8738-b009-4120-9ec1-417a6ea1a61f","time":1445260986752},"expires":1453096786752}
```

And the `len` of this new string is also `99`.

---

**Option 2**

Using the replace method as follows (just tried here and it worked well)

```
string_02 = string_01.replace(' ', '')

[Out]: {"data":{"id":"10ba8738-b009-4120-9ec1-417a6ea1a61f","time":1445260986752},"expires":1453096786752}
```

It removes the spaces and gives a string with length `99`.

---

**Notes:**

- As I was not able to reproduce OP's problem with `.replace()`, I used it as the Option 2. However, if that doesn't do the work, I suggest going with Option 1.
- With both cases, the `len` of the string was reduced and the spaces as well, as one can see from the outputs.