# Cannot remove spaces or trim spaces from column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, trim

I'm stuck in simple task. I have a test dataframe with spaces in it.
In order to remove them I did following:

```
df_unique['final'] = df_unique['final'].astype("string")
df_unique['final'] = df_unique['final'].str.strip()
df_unique['final'] = df_unique['final'].str.replace(' ', '')
```

But still:

```
df_unique = 

final
+123 123
+123 123 123
+12345 123
```

`df_unique.info()` show the column as String.

---

I think it is not working for DOUBLE spaces numbers. Idk maybe this information will help you

Comment: This works fine here: `df['final'].str.replace(' ', '')`.

Comment: @PaulS Yep, I know. It is working fine for most of column values, but for some it is not

Comment: So, maybe you should post an example where that fails, @Mamed!

Comment: I guess that when that fails, you do not have spaces, but characters that look as spaces but not being spaces. `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` may help you to spot them.

Comment: I almost forgot stack people sometimes being funny :D There is an example guys

Comment: This may help you, @Mamed: [Is there something that looks like white space but it is not and how to remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370094/is-there-something-that-looks-like-white-space-but-it-is-not-and-how-to-remove-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the dataframe is called `df` and looks like the following

```
         final
0      123 123
1  123 123 123
2    12345 123
```

Assuming that the goal is to create a new column, let's call it `new`, and store the values of the column `final`, but without the spaces, one can create a custom lambda function using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) as follows

```
import re

df['new'] = df['final'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s', '', x))

[Out]:
         final        new
0      123 123     123123
1  123 123 123  123123123
2    12345 123   12345123
```

If one wants to update the column `final`, then do the following

```
df['final'] = df['final'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s', '', x))

[Out]:
  
       final
0     123123
1  123123123
2   12345123
```

Another option for this last use case would be using [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) as

```
df['final'] = df['final'].str.replace(r'\s', '', regex=True)

[Out]:

       final
0     123123
1  123123123
2   12345123
```

Note:

- One needs to pass `regex=True`, else one will get

> FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version